# How to display input from textbox in a multiple lined textbox?

Tags: c#, class

I need to make a program that takes the input of a textbox (tb_1) and puts it in the second textbox (tb_2, multilined) when a button is pressed. It also needs to paste the code a specific amount of times, depending on the numericupdown digit. I have come this far, what do i do next? Thanks in advance.
(Note: it should probably be done within a class.)

```
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tb_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string tekst = tb_1.Text;
        tb_2.Text = tekst + Environment.NewLine;
        tb_1.Clear();
        tb_2.Text = tekst + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: How about simply using a `for`-loop to add the text as often as you want?

Comment: What are you able to do with this code? What issue you  are facing with this code?

Comment: Try using AppendText https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 and add Environment.NewLine as needed.

Comment: Homework is about learning through trial and error. The only hint you should need is use a loop and a stringbuilder.

Comment: @S.Akbari my question is, how can i make it work that the input text from tb_1 will be added under previously added text? If i press the button twice now it will replace the first input, instead of list the second input below the first.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Right now, the input from tb_1 gets put in tb_2 when the button is pressed, like it should. however, the second time the button is pressed, the input should come below the first input, and that is the part i'm struggling at right now.

Comment: Should be `tb_2.Text = tb_2.Text + tb_1.Text + Environment.NewLine;` What you want to do is set a debug breakpoint and examine how the involved variables get changed.

Comment: @SteveGreene Okay i finished that part. How do i make it display the amount of times the numericupdown gives?

Comment: You need to Read about how to use loops

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) { ... }` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_for_loop.htm